# SSH ProxyJump with key on jump host

Tags: ssh

I'm trying to connect to a server through a jump host. I usually do this by first logging in to the jump host and using a key which is deposited there to log in to the server. Agent forwarding is disabled to the jump host.
I've found a shorthand which works:

```
ssh -t jump ssh server
```

But I'd like to make use of ProxyJump in .ssh/config.

Whenever I add a directive, it seems like it's trying to log in to the server with the key on my client and not the key on the jump host. How can I change that?

Comment: Going by the manual, can you try adding an `IdentityFile` directive to the `Host` stanza for the final server? The same stanza would have the `ProxyJump` option set. The `IdentityFile` directive would point to the key on the jump host.

Comment: That's what I thought as well. But the IdentityFile directive seems to only be looking on the initial host. If I use IdentityFile I get `no such identity: /home/foo/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such file or directory`.

Answer (score 9):

This is how the ProxyJump works -- it logs you to the first host, initiates IO forwarding and then logs you to the second host with the credentials in your local machine. This is the safer way since your credentials never leave your machine nor does the agent forwarded socket.

Move the key from the jumpbox to your machine or set up the authentication on the second host to accept your local credential/keys.

There is no simple way around that since the openssh developers are not interested in promoting bad security practices.

Comment: Is there absolutely no way to change this behavior? I didn't make this setup and I'm sure the people that did, did it for a reason.

Comment: No, there is not. I would like to hear that reason from these people. The key on that jump server is not more secure than the key in your system.

Comment: only thing you can use is the `RemoteCommand` to execute the second ssh jump, but I do not find it very helpful if you would like to configure more servers to connect to through that single host.

Comment: @Jakuje our team was really interested in this. We were thinking this way: if a team member joins or leaves the team, it's easier to change keys on just one server (the jumpbox). Could you please elaborate why this is a bad security practice? Thanks!

Comment: @MaxMalysh Because keys on the jump host can not be protected in any way (unless they would be stored in cryptographic hardware). And because you do not have any audit trail behind the jump box if you do it this way -- all connection would come with the same key from the same host. You could probably try to correlate logs from different hosts to get some guess, but it is fragile. If you want to make easy to change keys, use certificates, some IdM solution handling the keys for you or at least AuthorizedKeysCommand pulling the keys from centralized place.

Comment: @Jakuje got it, thanks!

Comment: I ran into it while trying to use sftp from a friend's computer (so quite trusted) without copying my private key.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using the default key(s), where the key for the jumphost is on your local `~/.ssh` directory and the key for the remote machine is in the `~/.ssh` directory of the jumphost:

```
ssh -t <jumphost> "ssh -t <remote-machine>"
```

and if you want to specify the paths of the keys:

```
ssh -it <local-path-to-your-jumphost-key> <jumphost> "ssh -ti <path-on-jumphost-for-remote-machine-key> <remote-machine>"
```